# Tkinter DateEntry format yyyy/mm/dd works on Linux, but not on Microsoft Windows

Tags: linux, date, tkinter

I have the following code which works fine in Linux. However the date_pattern='yyyy/mm/dd' is not working in Microsoft Windows. In Linux the field shows 2021/08/16. Same exact code in Windows shows 8/16/2021. I looked around in several sites, including stackoverflow, but could not find this exact issue being brought up.

There might be an other way to change the date format so as to make it work in both Linux and Windows, but I don't know one. I would appreciate if you could guide me to the correct instructions or show me how to make it compatible.

```
lbl_started = tk.Label(data_frame, text="Started:")
lbl_started.place(x=175, y=60, height=20, width=60)
entry_started = DateEntry(data_frame, locale='en_US', date_pattern='yyyy/mm/dd', width=33, font=('FreeSans', 11), bg="#E8F9FF")
entry_started.place(x=232, y=55, height=25, width=90)

lbl_completed = tk.Label(data_frame, text="Completed:")
lbl_completed.place(x=338, y=60, height=20, width=70)
entry_completed = DateEntry(data_frame, locale='en_US', date_pattern='yyyy/mm/dd', width=33, font=('FreeSans', 11), bg="#E8F9FF")
entry_completed.place(x=411, y=55, height=25, width=90)
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: It shows `2021/08/17` in my Python 3.8.10 and tkcalendar v1.6.1.

Comment: Interesting. In Linux I use Python 3.8.10 and tkcalendar v1.6.1 too. However, Windows uses tkcalendar 1.2.1. This might be the issue, caused by different version of tkcalendar. I will update the version in Windows and see if it make a difference.

Comment: Upgrading tkcalendar to v1.6.1 resolved the issue with date format.